# How to get the error summary separately from a response body using curl in shell script

Tags: shell, curl

I am trying to get the status code and exit status from the response of an api request using curl in shell script.

```
status_code=$(curl --write-out %{http_code} --silent --output /dev/null -X POST http://..............)
exit_status="$?"
echo "$status_code"
echo "$exit_status"
```

I am getting both the things.But now i also want the error summary(if its there any) from the reponse and to be printed.How can i do that?

Below is the example of my response code

```
{
    "errorCode": "E0000014",
    "errorSummary": "Update of credentials failed",
    "errorLink": "E0000014",
    "errorId": "oaeKE7Weyp7RsKYDNR2V0Sw9w",
    "errorCauses": [
        {
            "errorSummary": "Old Password is not correct"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get the `errorSummary` inside the `errorCauses` i.e. I want to print the `"Old Password is not Correct"` string(Or whatever the strings come). I have tried but couldn't find any solution for it

Comment: So, the body of the HTTP response in addition to the HTTP response code?

Comment: No. I just want the errorSummary value. Or if possible is there a way to get any field value if I want?

Answer (score 1):

Change curl to store the response document (instead of sending  it to /dev/null), and use jq to extract the first components of the errorCauses array.

```
curl ... -output response.txt -X ...
exit_status="$?"
...
jq '.errorCauses[0].errorSummary' < response.txt
```

Comment: is there a way that I can get it without using the jq

Comment: If you are 100% sure about the formatting of the output (e.g., line breaks), you can use line oriented text processing (sed, awk). Otherwise, you will need a tool capable of parsing JSON file - Python, Perl or JQ